BLDC fan control with UART
I have a BLDC motor, which I need to control for fan application.
How can I implement it using UART where an input(code) is entered by the user and the motor changes it speed according to the input given by the user? I'm working with a new microcontroller. The algorithm used is sensor-less FOC for controlling. It is similar to SAM-E70 controller for BLDC motor control.
(I want to control the motor using UART instead of IR. I do have a code for IR, but now I want to implement it using just UART)

Please, specify what control circuit you "BLDC fan" have, and "IR code" for what you have.
